# How to overwrite files in VS Code on copy-paste (and not get a *.1* appended to the filename)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste, overwrite

Whenever I copy-paste a file in **VS Code**'s project pane from one folder to another with an existing file of the same name, it keeps appending a `.1` in the filename.

(ex: `bob.jpg` **->** `bob.1.jpg`).

Is there a way to disable this and have it overwrite the file instead (or at least prompt to confirm the overwrite)?

Example of project folder:

```
[folder] images_1
        bob.jpg   //copy this
[folder] images_2
        bob.jpg   //to replace this one here...
```

For now, I'm forced to do it through *Windows Explorer*, but if there's a way I'd sure like the answer! :)

Comment: Did anyone find answer to this ?

Answer (score 11):

Incremental naming can be disabled as of v1.72, see [release notes:incremental  naming](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#ability-to-disable-incremental-naming-in-file-explorer):

> ##### Ability to disable incremental naming, in file explorer
>
> A new value of disabled has been introduced to the
> `explorer.incrementalNaming` setting. This allows for completely
> disabling any logic surrounding changing the file name on paste within
> the explorer. If the file name is already present you will be prompted
> to overwrite the existing file, similar to most native explorers.

Comment: It's about time! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of a hack but I delete the file I'd like to replace, then paste the new one.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to gather, incremental naming patterns are forced when performing duplicate copy-paste operations within VS Code itself. The VS Code team were [not so keen on the idea](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127746) of changing that, either.

*Windows Explorer* drag and drop seems to be the best "workaround" for this to date.